# Issue in booting Windows 10 after installing Linux on a USB drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub, elementaryos

I have recently installed **elementary OS** on a USB drive from a system running Windows 10, but I booted live from elementary OS DVD for installation purposes.

Now every time I boot my PC without the USB drive, an error is displayed:

```
error: no such device:
error: unknown file system

Entering rescue mode.....
grub rescue>
```

From what I learned it seemed that I need to reinstall the OS and change the mount point to where the windows partition is located, but I have already done many changes to the OS so I don't want to lose any of it... So is there any way to change the mount point without reinstalling or any other way to cure this disease?

Comment: *"I have recently installed elementary OS on a USB drive ... Now every time I boot my PC without the USB drive, an error is displayed"* -- You're leaving out too many details.  Are you still trying to boot Windows?  Did you successfully install Linux for dual booting?  If the Linux root filesystem was installed on the USB drive, then what rootfs do you expect to use when there is no USB drive?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to boot windows without the USB, Yes, Linux is successfully installed and rolling, I expect to run windows normally after removal of the USB.

Comment: You're asking a XY question.  You need to rewrite your post to clearly indicate that the issue is booting Win 10 after installing Linux on a USB drive.  You're just guessing that changing a *"mount point"* is going to fix your problem, but that not the issue at all.  The real problem is probably with Grub (which is probably on the USB drive).

Comment: Changed the questions. Thanks for the guide. By the way do you have a solution ??

Comment: *"By the way do you have a solution ?"* -- No, you need a Grub expert.  You probably need to create a small boot partition on your main disk drive (and redirect the boot sector to read that partition).